# Does DatabaseIntegrityCheck.sql log to text files in disk?

Tags: sql-server

I want to setup checkdb using DatabaseIntegrityCheck.sql from [Ola-hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/). I have passed LogToTable = 'Y'. But will it log to disk as well in text files? I did not find any parameter for that.

P.S. I know that jobs from MaintenanceSolution.sql do log to files in disk.

Script reference : [DatabaseIntegrityCheck.sql](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-integrity-check.html)

Comment: If you're referencing a script that isn't part of the SQL Server installation, you should really be citing it. Not everyone is familiar with Ola Hallengren's work.

Comment: yes. i wanted to add ola-hallengren as tag. But it said that i need at least 1500 rep to add new tag as there was no existing tag. so I asked without it

Comment: I don't mean tag it (Ola shouldn't be it's own tag anyway), I mean provide a link to the script/documentation/etc.

Comment: done. added the reference to the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure do not, byt itself log to disk. There isn't really any clean way to write to disk from inside T-SQL. Hence using an output file in the job step (like what the create job section of MaintenanceSolution does).